# iphone loss of tabbar during uimodaltransition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Okay, working on a transition between a view with a tabbar and another view which is to be an information/about view. I have the code to transition from the view with tabbar and to transition back to previous view, but during the transition back I lose the tabbar at the bottom. Not sure exactly how to approach this with the tabbar in the MainWindow.xib

E.g.:

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
  {
  TablesViewController *tvc = [[TablesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TablesView"  bundle:nil];

  tvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
  [self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES];
  [tvc release];

}

Thanks,
np

Answer (score 1):

Try presenting the modal transition from the containing instance of UITabBarController and not the UIViewController the action was triggered from.

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    TablesViewController *tvc = [[TablesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TablesView" bundle:nil;
    tvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES];
    [tvc release];
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand how to do this. I have the UITabBarController declared in the appDelegate of the program?

Comment: The calling UIViewController should have a reference to its UITabBarController automatically... The code I've presented should work as is.

Comment: How are you dismissing the modal controller? Remember that the controller that started the transition is responsible for dismissing it... If you look at the 'Utility Application' template in Xcode, you can see how Apple recommends you achieve this using delegation.

Comment: What I am attempting now is just creating a templated tab bar app then adding the coding from the utility app. Where I run into trouble is in the done method. It has the

Comment: Hey, finally got it to work correctly. Did not have the delegate synthesized so this was causing the crash I believe. Thanks for taking the time to help me through and give some guidance. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, did a ugly solution:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender { 
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```